# mutual references between php instances

Tags: php, codeigniter

Last night when I was adding a library class(named Mongoq) in Codeigniter, I found in library class when we wanted to use super instacnce $CI's properties or functions we usually reference $CI like this
`$this->CI = &get_instance`

and when library class's instance was constructed completely, usually the library instance was assigned to $CI's property , in this case $CI->mongoq reference the lib instance talked above.

I realized $CI and $Mongoq have established mutual references, and then I var_dump both instance to find some detail about this mutual reference.

You know $CI->mongoq reference mongoq instance and mongoq instance have a reference point to $CI also.
So the value of $CI->mongoq is like this 
`["mongoq"]=>object(Mongoq)#22 (22){["CI":"Mongoq":private]=> *RECURSION*`

the value of Mongoq's property CI is RECURSION, dose somebody know more detail about this or dose mutual reference have some effects about php's efficiency. Appreciate first.

Comment: Take a look at `zend.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this relationship can go forever, right?

A ->B -> B->A ... etc.

The value is indeed correct, Recursion simply states that it's recursive, There's nothing wrong with it.

It comes into play when you try to json_encode objects with recursion, in which you need to take special care as sometimes errors will be thrown.

In short, *RECURSION* just shows in text what you explained in words here.